# How do I log exceptions from a Routing Slip Activity within MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

We've got a Routing slip activity which is throwing an exception, however, nothing is written to the logs when this errors.

I know we can listen to the `RoutingSlipFaulted` message and inspect the Exception, however, we'd also like it to be in the logs and maybe in the OTL data too.

Is there a way to stick something in to the pipeline for the activities to capture the error and log it like the normal consumers do?

Below is the log of running an activity that faulted.

```
16:31:32.516-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/activity3_execute
16:31:32.518-D SEND loopback://localhost/activity3_execute dc340000-5ece-a04a-f20d-08db5d351d93 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip
16:31:32.518-D RECEIVE loopback://localhost/Activity2_execute dc340000-5ece-a04a-f20d-08db5d351d93 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip Activity2(00:00:00.5259605)
16:31:32.523-D Execute Activity: dc340000-5ece-a04a-d752-08db5d351d92 (Activity3, loopback://localhost/Activity3_execute)
Done Activity 3
16:31:33.091-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/urn:message:MassTransit.Courier.Contracts:RoutingSlipActivityFaulted
16:31:33.096-D SEND loopback://localhost/urn:message:MassTransit.Courier.Contracts:RoutingSlipActivityFaulted dc340000-5ece-a04a-0382-08db5d351e97 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlipActivityFaulted
16:31:33.097-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/urn:message:MassTransit.Courier.Contracts:RoutingSlipFaulted
16:31:33.102-D SEND loopback://localhost/urn:message:MassTransit.Courier.Contracts:RoutingSlipFaulted dc340000-5ece-a04a-ffe3-08db5d351e97 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlipFaulted
16:31:33.103-D RECEIVE loopback://localhost/Activity3_execute dc340000-5ece-a04a-f20d-08db5d351d93 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip Activity3(00:00:00.5843245)
```

Answer (score 1):

Faulted routing slip activities are handled different that consumer exceptions, and as such are not logged as errors since the routing slip compensation may expect them. And you're right, they are not logged either.

No real thoughts on whether this would be a useful addition, or create a bunch of noise for those used to the existing (not-logged) behavior.

If you created a filter on `ExecuteContext<T>` and added it, you would be able to log exceptions yourself.

> Actually, I'm just going to add this so that the exceptions are logged consistently.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be useful as an addition. Even if it's a warning like the retries.

Comment: It's in the 8.1 prerelease packages already!